# Load jQuery plugin after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin on the page. Plugin is extended with jQuery UI widget that adds the UI to the actual upload functionality.

Initialization on widget is bound to a jQuery page ready function like this:

```
(function ($, tmpl, loadImage) {
    'use strict';
    var parentWidget = ($.blueimpIP || $.blueimp).fileupload;
    $.widget('blueimpUI.fileupload', parentWidget, {...bla bla bla
```

On my page, a widget form is hidden (via display:none) at the beginning, and shows up only on user click, but if the form that widget uses is hidden when the page loaded even fires, the UI interaction functionality is malfunctioning. If the widget form is visible, everything initializes fine. All that happens despite the fact that I am actually calling a plug-in constructor no earlier then the widget form is shown, so the construction should take place fine.

Anyways, my question is: how do I load a JavaScript file at run time, so that it receives a page loaded event (manual call for this particular file perhaps?) and initializes as if it is initializing at page load?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want dynamic script loading, it just sounds like there's a problem in your existing code. Post a jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: Jeff, I agree that the problem is in the code, but the page is massive at this point, where I have decided to add the javascript file uploading functionality, so I will probably loose a lot of time extracting the problem part to jsfiddle. Dynamic loading was an idea to just have the problem solved in a "dirty" way, since the code is for personal use and not for production.